# web3py python get exact value swap tokens

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I'm using web3py to swap tokens, using the "**swapExactETHForTokens**" function, it's working perfectly, with the return hash I use the "[web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?highlight=get_transaction_receipt#web3.eth.Eth.get_transaction_receipt)" function to get the transaction details, but I couldn't find how get the exact amount of tokens that went into my wallet.

I found [this other topic](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80135/getting-tokens-transferred-from-web3-py) answered with the same question, but I didn't understand the answer or I'm too new to web3py for this.

what I really want is to get the final value of the token obtained in the swap as shown in the image below

[image]

I don't know if I'm looking for this information the wrong way, but I haven't found any other material on the subject on web3py.

Comment: this could be answer you looking for
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73809133/decode-input-from-uniswap-v3-transaction-left-data-attribute-undecoded/73823226#73823226)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event logs in the transaction, from that you should be able to calculate the amount of Bomber Coins that were transferred.

Comment: Would be nice to add some code (at least show that logs are part of the returned receipt, and possibly how to decode them) to this answer.