# decode 'input' from Uniswap V3 transaction left 'data' attribute undecoded

Tags: filter, decode, web3py, uniswap

I'm trying to read pending transactions that goes to UniswapV3 using this code in async way

```
address_router = "0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45"
with open("abiRouterUniswapV3.json", "r") as myFile:
data = myFile.read()
abiRouter = json.loads(data)

contractRouter = w3.eth.contract(address=address_router, abi=abiRouter)

block_filter = w3.eth.filter('pending')

def handle_event(event):
try:
    tx = w3.eth.getTransaction(event)
    tx_to = tx.to
except Exception:
    pass
else:
    if tx_to == "0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45": #filtering only UniswapV3 
        input_decoded = contractRouter.decode_function_input(tx.input)
        print("hash: ", tx.hash.hex())
        print(input_decoded)
```

I'm using the ABI of UniswapV3 Router to create the contractRouter and make the decodification, however It doesn't decode the 'data' inside the 'input' when the function is Multicall. As an example it gave this result when the function is Multicall

hash:  0x907b4c17bc525786960c4b2373c1b60cafc3f287e95cf5948432e4e71b25dd00
(<Function multicall(uint256,bytes[])>, {'deadline': 1663819751, 'data': [b'G+C\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1ck\xf5&4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x029\xc5\x0f\x85c\xf09@5\xf5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xfb\xc9\xc2\xa8\x8d\x98;\xa1\xe3\xe6(\x11Y\xe9\x98\xa4\xc9\x1aC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0*\xaa9\xb2#\xfe\x8d\n\x0e\O'\xea\xd9\x08<ul\xc2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\xee\xc9\x13"\x95\xc1\xfd|\xab\x0b,\xfd\xe6z\x15\xaa\x94W\xd7']})

You can see that 'data' wasn't decode

What is wrong in my code or what I'm missing?. I will really appreciate any help or guide you can provide me

Answer (score 0):

so you mean you wanna get event from data. when you want to get data decode you should find event from abi where like uniswap pair or somewhere you need to check interface and you can use event contract like this e.g)swap

```
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
pairContract = w3.eth.contract(address = pairAddress, abi = pairAbi)
swap = pairContract.events.Swap()
events = swap.processReceipt(tx_receipt, errors=DISCARD)
amount0_out = events[-1]["args"]["amount0Out"]
amount1_out = events[-1]["args"]["amount1Out"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mun_sunouk, in my case TransactionReceipt doesnt work since what I want is to know the pending transactions still not mined and TransactionReceipt only works for mined transacctions. Thank you for your time for reading and make a reply on my post

Answer (score -3):

Here is our I solved a similar issue trying to decode the data input of a multicall function on the ethereum network using web3py

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
import requests

#Txn Hash 0x7567fb85fadd0a9e53d278f56e7ceaabaf4947af5c44d5a5327fbfc24543717c

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed2.binance.org/"))

sample_input= "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"

v3pcsRouter= web3.toChecksumAddress('0x13f4EA83D0bd40E75C8222255bc855a974568Dd4')

v3pcsAbi=" Enter ABI"
v3pcsContract = web3.eth.contract(address=v3pcsRouter, abi=v3pcsAbi)

decoded = v3pcsContract.decode_function_input(sample_input)


print(decoded)

multicall_data = decoded[1]['data'][0]

nested_call_decoded = v3pcsContract.decode_function_input(multicall_data)

print(nested_call_decoded)
```